# why error : no matching function for call in c++ list

Tags: c++, list, std, erase

i want to delete an element in "m_list"

but this code occurs error " no matching function for call to list::erase"

ex)

```
std::list<std::list<Myclass *>::iterator> **m_list;

std::list<Myclass *>::iterator it;
std::list<Myclass *>::iterator dlt;
for(it = m_list[a]->begin(); it != m_list[a]->end(); it++ ) {
  if ((*it)->condition = true) {
    dlt = m_list[a]->erase(it);   // error detected here
  }
}
```

i don't know why list::erase doesn't work

Someone answer me how to solve this problem please...

Comment: It should already fail at `it = m_list[a]->begin()`. The type of `it` is wrong (Or rather your logic in the loop is probably wrong.) Consider what type `m_list[a]` is and what type then `m_list[a]->begin()` is.

Comment: When erasing from a list that you're iterating over in the loop, you should _not_ use `it++` in the for-loop itself. Instead, increment it in the loop body, but only if you don't erase. _i.e._ `if ((*it)->condition) it = m_list[a]->erase(it); else ++it;` ... this is because erasing invalidates the iterator, and that's also why it returns a new one.

Comment: `std::list<std::list<Myclass *>::iterator> **m_list;` is odd, It's a pointer to pointer. it never was assigned. so it cannot work the way it is shown

Comment: Storing iterators in different container is risky because of iterator invalidation. Result of `begin()` would be `std::list<std::list<Myclass *>::iterator>::iterator` which is even odder.

Comment: `(*it)->condition = true` should be `(*it)->condition == true`, or even better just `(*it)->condition`.